# Not sure I understand Memcached properly - Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

A simple DB select query retrieves the info (call it for simplicity the **page_id**) to build web pages for different users on an application I built. I recently learned about Memcached and found [this](http://culttt.com/2014/01/06/working-cache-laravel-4/) useful post.

Suppose 2 users (A and B, using different machines/browsers) use the application I wrote. Let's say user A is chronologically the first user and B is the second.

Suppose a flow such as this:

```
$ID = 1000; // $ID retrieves the page_id to build the page

if (Cache::has('page_id')) {

    $pageID = Cache::get('page_id');

} else {

  $sql = DB::table('mytable')->select('page_id')->where('id', $ID)->first();

  $pageID = $sql->page_id;

  Cache::forever('page_id', $pageID);

}

//Now build the page using $pageID
```

Here's the question. User A populates the Cache on the first trip to the page, but if user A reloads or revisits the same page, the Cache will serve up the **page_id**. But how about user B? (user B visits the same page after user A, user B uses different machine & browser) Now to make an analogy, I know our CDN serves up a cached image/resource to users A and B both. Similarly here, does the application Cache serve up **page_id** for user B also, or does user B get the **page_id** from the DB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any particular caching key, all users will get the same data.

For this reason, it's important if you're storing something like a user's profile information, you don't want to store it with a cache key like `profile` - you'd want to store it with a unique key name like `profile-123` (where 123 is the user's ID).